# Include Third Party Jars in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I have added Gson API to my MapReducing Program. When I am running the program getting;

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
```

Can anybody suggest me to how to add Third Party Libraries to Hadoop?

Comment: Check out this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345923/how-to-import-org-apache-java-dependancies

Comment: It would be better if you show us your code.

Comment: Check my answer here, I have explained all the available options to fix this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36227260/1766402

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to add any dependencies to both the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `-libjars` upon submitting a job like in the following examples:

Use the following to add all the jar dependencies from current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that when starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars of any dependencies through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.

Comment: I tried your advise by doing like..
    bin/hadoop jar /home/Projects/MyMaprunner/dist/progenMaprunner.jar -libjars /home/hadoopJar/gson-2.2.2.jar /myData /output arg1 arg2

got exception as
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/MyDesktop/-libjars

Comment: Check the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890087/problem-with-libjars-in-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Add the Jar in HADOOP_CLASSPATH

```
    vi $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

Add last line

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/root/hadoop/extrajars/java-json.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

"/root/hadoop/extrajars/java-json.jar" is path on linux box itself and not on HDFS

Restart the hadoop

Command

```
hadoop classpath
```

Should show the jar in classpath

Now run MR job as usual

```
hadoop jar <MR-program jar> <MR Program class> <input dir> <output dir>
```

It will use the file from as expected.